# Android mixed language text - BidiFormatter on String with RTL and LTR text

Tags: java, android, locale, bidirectional, bidi

I have a `ListView` with custom `View` where I have a `TextView` :

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textViewItemTitle"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
     android:text="title" />
```

This `TextView` contains Hebrew text.

```
 if(!bidi.isRtl(event)){
     event = bidi.unicodeWrap(event);
 }

 holder.title.setText(String.format("%s  %s  %s", bidi.unicodeWrap(item.getStartTimeNoDate().trim()), event,
 bidi.unicodeWrap(item.getDuration().trim())));
```

Where the first argument is time hh:mm:ss, second (event) is a Hebrew String and third like the first.

**The problem:**  some time the event String contains mixed text in Hebrew and English like `abc-אבג` then all the text behave like the the gravity is left (and not right like I defined in the text view), I mean indented to left.

How to solve that?

Comment: Maybe you can post a screenshot to illustrate. Which system did you check? Implementations may be OEM-specific.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot post a screenshot and I tested thta on several devices with different Android versions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding to your TextView:

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

For more reading:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection

Comment: android:textDirection can be used only for API level 17+.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer will do the job when the text is in a `TextView`. This is a more general answer, applicable both to the basic/happy scenario and to other, more complicated use cases.

There are situations when mixed-language text is to be used someplace other than inside a `TextView`. For instance, the text may be passed in a share `Intent` to Gmail or WhatsApp and so on. In such cases, you must use a combination of the following classes:

- [`BidiFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/text/BidiFormatter.html)
- [`TextDirectionHeuristics`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextDirectionHeuristics.html)

As quoted in the documentation, these are ...

> Utility class[es] for formatting text for display in a potentially opposite-directionality context without garbling. The directionality of the context is set at formatter creation and the directionality of the text can be either estimated or passed in when known.

So for example, say you have a `String` that has a combination of English & Arabic, and you need the text to be

- ***right-to-left*** (RTL).
- always ***right-aligned***, even if the sentence begins with English.
- English & Arabic words in the correct sequence and without garbling.

then you could achieve this using the `unicodeWrap()` method as follows:

```
String mixedLanguageText = ... // mixed-language text

if(BidiFormatter.getInstance().isRtlContext()){
    Locale rtlLocale = ... // RTL locale
    mixedLanguageText = BidiFormatter.getInstance(rtlLocale).unicodeWrap(mixedLanguageText, TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR);
}
```

This would convert the string into RTL and align it to the left, if even one RTL-language character was in the string, and fallback to LTR otherwise. If you want the string to be RTL even if it is completely in, say English (an LTR language), then you could use `TextDirectionHeuristics.RTL` instead of `TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR`.

This is the proper way of handling mixed-direction text in the absence of a `TextView`. Interestingly, as the documentation states,

> Also notice that these direction heuristics correspond to the same types of constants provided in the `View` class for `setTextDirection()`, such as `TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL`.

**Update:**

I just found the [`Bidi`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Bidi.html) class in Java which seems to do something similar. Look it up!

**Further references:**

**1.** [**Write text file mix between arabic and english**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24723273).

**2.** [**Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm**](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and I am targeting API 16
My solution was very simple, I added to the beginning of the String "\u200F"

```
String mixedLanguageText = ... // mixed-language text
newText = "\u200F" + mixedLanguageText;
```

"\u200F" = Unicode Character 'RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK' (U+200F)

Comment: solved the problem, but its have a conflict when using SpannableString

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet demonstrates how to use unicodeWrap():

```
String mySuggestion = "15 Bay Street, Laurel, CA";
BidiFormatter myBidiFormatter = BidiFormatter.getInstance();

// The "did_you_mean" localized string resource includes
// a "%s" placeholder for the suggestion.
String.format(R.string.did_you_mean,
        myBidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(mySuggestion));
```